# FluentFTP has old dependency to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: c#, fluentftp

Currently I am developing a azure function. I use Net6.0. I have multiple imports. At least one with ftp and one with http.

So I imported both packages via nuget. But if I start my function, the following error occurs:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

This error is thrown because of a dependency of `FluentFTP`:

[image]

If I downgrade `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` to Version 6.0.0. The application starts without any error. Or, if I remove the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package, it also works (then the depency has version 2.2.0).

But why is this a problem with the newest version? Is there a way of using all packages with the newest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting `net6.0` and the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` dependency you are trying to install is meant for `net7.0`.

You can check that versions are named according to the .net version - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/7.0.0#versions-body-tab

That is why you should use `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` version `6.0.0` or below.

Comment: Oh well, it is that easy. I thougt the version of the packages are randomly like the net version. But thank you!